# Cannot get image when uploading to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Im trying to upload to a facebook fan page album. I have permissions and the access token (I can post to the wall).

This is my code:

```
$img = realpath('/var/www/publish_facebook/images/corn.jpg');

$args = array(
          'message' => 'testing',
          'source' => '@' . $img,
          'aid' => $album_id,
          'no_story' => 1,
          'access_token' => $fanpage_token
        );

try
{
    var_dump($args);
    $photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
} 
catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
{
     return 'Error facebookservice'.$e;
}
```

And I get the error:

> Error facebookserviceOAuthException: (#324) Requires upload file

When I remove the `@` before the image path I get the same error. If I use `source` or `image` as the parameter, I still get the same error. The `var_dump` result is:

```
array(5) { ["message"]=> string(7) 
            "testing" ["source"]=> string(68) "@http://www.blog.webintelligence.ie/publish_facebook/images/corn.jpg" 
            ["aid"]=> string(15) "531304096943185" 
            ["no_story"]=> int(1) 
           ["access_token"]=> string(198) <page access token>
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don’t _guess_ parameter names, but read the docs instead please: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#photos

Comment: Yes, I meant to say I also tried source, both with and without the @ and still getting the same error. Will edit question

Comment: Did you initialize the PHP SDK with file upload support? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setFileUploadSupport/

Comment: OK, added that as an answer, feel free to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter has to be named `source`, not image,

and you have to initialize the PHP SDK with [file upload support set to true](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setFileUploadSupport/) as well.